# SSRS 2019- Users in Browser Role cannot edit their own SSRS subscriptions

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2019, ssrs-subscription

I am using SSRS 2019 version and noticed the issue that users in the Browser role cannot edit their own created subscription. However, they can create and delete their subscription. is there any workaround to allow users to edit their subscription or it's a bug in SQL Server 2019 reporting services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting default to false in Report Server E-Mail Configuration fixed the issue for me . Thank you

True
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/e-mail-settings-reporting-services-native-mode-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

This is based on SSRS 2016 but have you checked the role permissions from SSMS ?

[image]

As you can see here, the browser role normally has "Manage Individual Subscriptions" permission active.

Comment: Yes, I have checked and have same default permission selected for Browser role. This is error log and unable to find root cause.

|ERROR|129|OData exception occurred: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: A delivery error has occurred.  Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InvalidExtensionParameter: One of the extension parameters is not valid for the following reason: The account you are using does not have administrator privileges. A subscription cannot be created for gajendra.singh@companydomain.com.

Comment: Sorry I can't help. You might want to **edit** your question and include this extra info there. If you also state that you have checked the permissions (include a screenshot like above) then I will delete this answer. It was too big to add as a comment.